# finding index of multiple items in a list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list

```
myList = ["what is your name", "Hi, how are you",
          "What about you", "How about a coffee", "How are you"]
```

Now I want to search index of all occurrence of `"How"` and `"what"`. How can I do this in Pythonic way?

Comment: What if `How` or `what` appears more than once in a string? And what about case sensitivity?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a one-liner Python is able to do!

```
[i for i, j in enumerate(myList) if 'how' in j.lower() or 'what' in j.lower()]
```

Comment: Has anyone really tried this one? It should be `j.lower()`, i is the index, right?

Comment: @lord63.j Yup, my bad. Forgot to change it when I first changed `[j for ...` to `[i for ...`

Answer (score 1):

This will work, but assumes you do not care about case sensitivity:

```
myList = ["what is your name","Hi, how are you","What about you","How about a coffee","How are you"]
duplicate = "how are you"
index_list_of_duplicate = [i for i,j in enumerate(myList) if duplicate in j.lower()]
print index_list_of_duplicate
     [1,4]
```

Comment: He wanted indexes, so it should be `[j for i, j...]` ;)

Comment: no, `j` is the entry of the list, `i` is the number from `enumerate`

Comment: Oops, silly me. This is what happens when you haven't been around python for ages

Comment: Pfiew. I think I went crazy for a second :P